# Using BCrypt, and generating salts

Tags: php, salt, encryption, bcrypt

SO.

I want to use BCrypt for my user authentication form. 
I can register a user using the code

```
<?php
$salt = '$2a$07$R.gJb2U2N.FmZ4hPp1y2CN$';
crypt("secretpassword", $salt);
?>
```

Here instead of using a constant salt. I want to generate random salts using

```
// Posted Code from http://pastebin.com/wLxDEhD7.
$Allowed_Chars =
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789./';
$Chars_Len = 63;
$salt = "";
for($i=0;$i<45 ;$i++)
{
    $salt .= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0,$Chars_Len)];
}
```

And store it into the database. Until this I am clear(I Hope :D)
Next what I need is to check the password when the user logs in.
For that I need the user's input data, the salt used for that user.

```
crypt("secretpassword", $salt);
```

I can get the user input, but how will I know the salt that has been used?
I am not clear on this.

Codes have been copied from phpmaster.com and http://pastebin.com/wLxDEhD7 (from a question asked on SO, I am unable to find the question again)
This is being used purely for educational purposes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: umm, am not getting it correctly, please bear with me.
am i supposed to store the hash in database?
idk, is that a good idea?

Comment: What [Kitsune](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352849/using-bcrypt-and-generating-salts#comment19954360_14352900) said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The salt is stored within the hash generated by BCrypt. So just doing this will work:

```
$passwordIsOk = crypt($password, $hash) === $hash;
```

Comment: Thanks,
So u mean that while verifying the password of the user when they login, I do not need the salt used? I can simply use
if(crypt($userpass,$hash) === $hash; ?
what is data stored in $hash ?

Comment: Right, you do not need to store the salt since it's going to be embedded inside the hash by BCrypt.

Comment: what does the $hash store?

Comment: @SworoopMahapatra `$hash` is the previous output of a `crypt()` command. It's a formatted string that includes the algorithm used, the salt, and the hash. The `crypt()` command accepts it as an argument, and will take the salt from it and apply it to the first parameter as a salt. Salting is intended to prevent hackers from being able to leverage pre-computed hash databases to easily crack the passwords, along with ensuring that all stored passwords have a unique hash (because some users will have the same password, which without the salt would mean they'd have the same hash).

Comment: Thanks Kitsune. Thanks Laurent. :)
All Cleared Up